# writing a function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote a function which converts a string into datetime. So,this is what I did

```
   CREATE FUNCTION formatit(
      @fromtime VARCHAR(50) -- varchar
       )
    RETURNS DATETIME
    AS 
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE @from varchar(50)
    DECLARE @value
      IF (CHARINDEX('NOON',@fromtime,0)) = 0 THEN

       SET @from = CONVERT(DATETIME, @fromtime) 
     ELSE
       SET @from =CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2000 12pm') 
    RETURN(@from)
    END

 SELECT dbo.formatit('04/12/2011 NOON ')
```

So, u can see that if fromtime consists of word NOON i'm trying to use a default date. But i've been getting a error  'Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.'

It works fine when I enter any time like 4 pm etc. but fails when i give noon. can u please letme know the way i can handle this?

Comment: If you want to use special values in time such as "Midnight", "Noon", "Dusk"  You must create the necessary if statements in your code to define those time values.

Comment: My suggestion would be to stop letting users type in things like "noon" - you're going to have to code hundreds of different IF statements for all the potential scenarios. Make them pick from a date/time picker control, then you can have complete power over how the strings are formatted, and not worry about *any* of these special cases.

Comment: @Aaron: It is a modiifcation to already existing site. So, I don't think i can change it now

Comment: Ok, well you have your work cut out for you.

Comment: `IF...THEN`? This is not VBScript. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

this works

```
 declare @from datetime

 SET @from =CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2000 12:00 pm')
```

---

The following was tested.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION formatit(
      @fromtime VARCHAR(50) -- varchar
       )
    RETURNS DATETIME
    AS 
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE @from datetime
     IF (CHARINDEX('NOON',@fromtime,0)) = 0 
       SET @from = CONVERT(DATETIME, @fromtime) 
     ELSE
       SET @from =CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2000 12pm') 
    RETURN(@from)
    END

 SELECT dbo.formatit('04/12/2011 NOON ')
```

Comment: I just ran it on the server.  did you change how you declare `@from`?

Comment: DO u think , my if statement is correct.. I get error at IF else.. i mean ur code

Comment: Pictures or it didn't happen.  OH LOOK a picture.

Comment: Yes your if statement had an extra `THEN` the code I posted works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the minutes after the 12, and put a space between the time and the AM/PM. See below:

```
SET @from = CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2000 12:00 PM')
```

Comment: If not, try `12:00:00.000 PM`

Answer (score 1):

@from is declared as varchar you are returning a datetime