# convert strings of type mm/dd/yyyy h to date time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a function which converts all of the strings to datetime.

```
 ALTER FUNCTION formatit(
  @fromtime VARCHAR(50) -- varchar
   )
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @from datetime
 IF (CHARINDEX('NOON',@fromtime,0)) = 0 
   SET @from = CONVERT(DATETIME, @fromtime) 
 ELSE
   SET @from =CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2000 12pm') 
RETURN(@from)
END

 SELECT dbo.formatit('04/12/2011 12 ')
```

So when u see the last select stmt it throws an error saying:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

It works fine if i give time 4 pm or 4:00. But it gives an error if i give just 4. Kindly let me know how i can handle this?

Comment: What does the 12 stand for? Is it assumed to be AM? PM? Is it military hours?

Comment: no man that's the problem. i have a table which consists of these weird values. Since, I'm enhancing the site  I need to somehow figure out how could i handle such issues. the end user just gives 12 and i need to handle it

Comment: To "handle it" don't you need to know whether the user meant midnight or noon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing a function in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366862/writing-a-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: Is the table data always in the format of "mm/dd/yyyy h" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a lot of code to look at the string and see if there is a ':' (like you have code to look for NOON). The problem is that if the string ends in 12PM the conversion will work too. So you would have to do something like

```
ALTER FUNCTION formatit(
  @fromtime VARCHAR(50) -- varchar
   )
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @from datetime
 IF (CHARINDEX('NOON',@fromtime,0)) <> 0 
 BEGIN
   SET @from =CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2000 12pm') 
 END
 ELSE IF (CHARINDEX('PM',@fromtime,0)) = 0 AND (CHARINDEX('AM',@fromtime,0)) = 0 AND (CHARINDEX(':',@fromtime,0)) = 0
 BEGIN
    SET @fromtime = @fromtime+':00'
    SET @from =CAST(@fromtime AS datetime)
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    SET @from =CAST(@fromtime AS datetime)
 END
 return(@from)
END
```

It looks like whitespace is ignored - I tried these and they all worked...

```
SELECT dbo.formatit('04/12/2011 12 ')
SELECT dbo.formatit('04/12/2011 12:00')
SELECT dbo.formatit('04/12/2011 12PM')
SELECT dbo.formatit('04/12/2011 12AM')
SELECT dbo.formatit('NOON')
```

Really you should look at the data you are using to feed this function with something other than TSQL so you have a better string parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `dbo.formatit('04/12/2011 12 ')` results in a call to `convert(datetime, '04/12/2011 12 ')`.  This string is not a valid input to convert to a date/time value.

See the list of formats in the [CAST and CONVERT reference in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  If you need to convert this string, you will need to change the time portion into "12:00PM" or just "12:00" (which is assumed to be in the 24-hour format).

Comment: k..is there a way through which i can get the time portion from that string and replace it with 12:00 pm

Answer (score 0):

First, I would find all the unique time occurrences in your table, something like:

```
select distinct rtrim(substring(@timeField,charindex(' ',@timeField)+1,99)) 
  as TimePortion
```

This will give you a sense of what you are dealing with.

Then, in your function, break apart the date and time portions...

Now, based on what you found from the query, you need to spell out what to do with the times you find.  For example, if the time portion is numeric, you might simply append :00 to it (i.e. 4 becomes 4:00).   If you see NOON, you might replace it with 12:00pm, etc.

```
ALTER FUNCTION formatit(    @fromtime VARCHAR(50)  )
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN 
    declare @dtPortion VARCHAR(12)
    declare @tmPortion VARCHAR(32)
    declare @x INT
    SET @x = charindex(' ',@fromTime)
    SET @dtPortion = left(@fromTime,@x-1)
    SET @tmPortion = rtrim(substring(@fromTime,@x+1,99))
    -- Figure out what to do

    SELECT @FromTime =
    CASE 
    WHEN IsNumeric(@tmPortion) = 1 THEN   @dtPortion+' '+@tmPortion+':00'
    WHEN @tmPortion = 'NOON' THEN  @dtPortion+' 12:00pm'
    ELSE
        @dtPortion+' 12:00pm'
    END                 

    SET @from =CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2000 12pm') 
    RETURN(@from)
END
Go
```

Hope this gets you started